# Is it correct to say "the reality between which he is torn sympathizing and vilifying"

Tags: american-english, british-english, formality, speech

what is the correct to write

> the reality between which he is torn sympathizing and vilifying

or

> the reality which he is torn between sympathizing and vilifying

Comment: I wouldn't advise writing it unless you are a well-recognized writer.

Comment: Thanks, Why, and is it a correct sentence. if not what is the correct one?

Comment: This is not a sentence that makes a lot of sense on any level. What the correct sentence is, depends on what you want to say. You've given us what you have so far, but you forgot to specify what it is that you want to have instead. It's like asking what the correct sentence is for "Red mathematics bulldozer yesterday". There are many possibilities, and it is unclear which of them you're after.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will edit it and then, take a look at it

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. I have a vague sense of what you're getting it, but it reads awkwardly. First of all, "between" implies at least two alternatives, but you're using in conjunction with the singular word "reality". I'd at least make that "realities". Even your second stab at it strikes me as missing something. The sentence is really confusing. If "reality" is your subject, I don't think you can either "sympathize a reality" or "vilify a reality". If you're talking about the reality of "his" condition, I think it really needs a rephrasing... something like, for instance, "The reality was, he was torn between sympathizing [with person X] or vilifying [person X]." I confess, though, I might be off-base with just what it is you're trying to get across. To be honest, I think you'd have to give us a fuller context than you have to get a decent answer.